# Loss of memory when system is mistakingly inactive

Tags: windows-8, memory, sleep, power-management

I have an application (FEM-Simulation) which runs about 24 hours and takes about 60%-70% of my memory. When I keep working or surfing during the simulation, it runs without any problems.

But when I leave the computer for more than 90 minutes, the application crashes pretending there was not enough memory.

I already checked all power options, there shouldn't be anything causing trouble. Do you have any ideas what could need so much memory after 90 minutes? Some scheduled tasks I don't know about? Where could I check?

My System:

AMD Phenom 955 BE

8GB DDR3-1333 RAM

Windows 8.1

Comment: Perhaps screen saver kicks in?   Try disabling it, just turn off monitor if necessary.

Comment: @lornix Okay I did turn off the monitor always, how does that affect the memory? Screen saver is also disabled